# pandas to sql turns datetime64 index to time zone aware

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have a `pandas` `Dataframe` with an index which is of type `datetime64[ns]`.
when I use the `to_sql` method i expect the index to be created as a `timestamp` postgres column, however it is creates a `timestamptz` column.

why would that be ?

Note that when the `datetime64[ns]` column is not an index but rather a normal column, this doesn't happen.

pandas 0.23.4, psycopg2 2.7.4, sqlalchemy 1.2.7, PostgreSQL 9.6.6

---

*example*

```
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='6h')
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'nums': range(5)}, index=dates)

                       nums
2018-01-01 00:00:00     0
2018-01-01 06:00:00     1
2018-01-01 12:00:00     2
```

inserting to postgres

```
df_test.to_sql('foo_table',postgres_uri,schema='data_test',index_label='info_date')
```

when reading from the database I get the index with different type

```
df_db = pd.read_sql_table('foo_table',postgres_uri,schema='data_test',index_col='info_date')

                           nums
                info_date                  
2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00   0
2018-01-01 06:00:00+00:00   1
2018-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   2
```

As you can see `info_date` is of type `datetime64[ns, UTC]`

Comment: I reported this as an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23510) on github

Answer (score 0):

I use mysql , but maybe if you set index=True?
i always use this code to write to my database:

```
df_test.to_sql(name='database', chunksize=20000, con=conn, index=True, if_exists='replace')
```

so maybe this will work:

`df_test.to_sql('foo_table',postgres_uri,schema='data_test',index=True)`